# Troubles with while loop and repaint() method

Tags: java

I am having a pile of troubles with using while loop and repaint() method. As you see in this codes, I put 2 lines to figure out whether the codes works fine or not. Those are 'System.out.println(x + " " + y + "Running");' and 'System.out.println("paint");'. The first one works fine. I checked the console. But the second one doesn't work. Could anyone help with this? And in order to make things clear, I put some additional explanations.

[This codes is a thread and called in an actionPerformed method located in main method like this.
"

```
giraffe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//giraffe is an Jbutton.

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String tmp = e.getActionCommand();
                if (tmp.equals("Giraffe")) {
                    AnimalObJects1 g1 = new AnimalObJects1(x, y);
                    array.add(g1);
                    panel.add(g1);
                    new Thread(g1).start();
                }
            }
        });
```

"]

```
package Zoo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax

.swing.*;

    public class AnimalObJects1 extends JPanel implements Animal, Runnable {
        int x, y;
        Rectangle2D.Double rectangle;
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse;
        Line2D.Double line;
        Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        ArrayList<Object> components = new ArrayList<Object>();
        ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
        Random generator = new Random();

        public AnimalObJects1(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.setOpaque(false);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }

        public void move() {

        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(x + " " + y + "Running");
                int a = generator.nextInt(4);

                if (a == 0)
                    x = x + generator.nextInt(30);
                else if (a == 1)
                    y = y + generator.nextInt(30);
                else if (a == 2)
                    x = x - generator.nextInt(30);
                else
                    y = y - generator.nextInt(30);
                this.setLocation(x, y);
                this.repaint();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            System.out.println("paint");
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            super.paintComponent(g2);
            g2.scale(0.5, 0.5);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(992, 296, 78, 520);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(780, 108, -1, 0);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(597, 582, 473, 234);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(828, 759, 242, 56);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(943, 245, 127, 51);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(991, 224, 128, 65);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1008, 188, 111, 73);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1008, 225, 211, 46);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1007, 188, 27, -39);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1009, 153, 34, 37);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1087, 150, 32, 38);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(948, 44, -112, 3);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1010, 138, 33, 15);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1088, 137, 32, 12);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1196, 224, 23, 18);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1065, 215, 51, 26);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 255);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1067, 64, 0, 0);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1081, 212, 23, 30);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(981, 37, 0, 0);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(671, 773, 62, 160);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(749, 783, 51, 149);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(941, 792, 52, 131);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1018, 784, 54, 132);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(194, 382, 0, 0);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(671, 915, 42, 128);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(750, 913, 35, 130);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(938, 899, 45, 135);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1021, 893, 40, 140);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(671, 1043, 43, 30);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(751, 1039, 33, 32);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(938, 1032, 44, 27);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1021, 1033, 38, 24);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(454, 670, 164, 38);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(947, 43, -1, 0);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(454, 677, 38, 26);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(244, 110, 0, 0);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(671, 901, 23, 19);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(749, 898, 25, 29);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(939, 886, 20, 11);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(939, 887, 23, 25);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(255, 255, 50);
            g2.setColor(color);
            rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(1020, 879, 30, 26);
            g2.fill(rectangle);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(rectangle);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1028, 303, 34, 44);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1006, 373, 21, 34);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1036, 424, 27, 31);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1002, 497, 31, 40);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1039, 555, 22, 39);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(967, 645, 59, 38);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(672, 631, 55, 32);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(789, 601, 37, 27);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(761, 668, 33, 24);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(677, 745, 27, 34);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(874, 703, 54, 36);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(795, 779, 31, 17);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(994, 754, 58, 36);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(689, 852, 21, 18);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(766, 950, 11, 21);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(959, 834, 23, 32);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(950, 982, 20, 23);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1034, 905, 16, 28);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1011, 244, 17, 22);
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(ellipse);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1113, 209, 1112, 209);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1068, 210, 1068, 210);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1068, 210, 1112, 208);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1112, 208, 1067, 208);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1067, 208, 1111, 207);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1111, 207, 1066, 206);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1066, 206, 1061, 212);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1061, 212, 1067, 211);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1067, 211, 1064, 210);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1064, 210, 1065, 209);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1065, 209, 1065, 209);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);

            color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            g2.setColor(color);
            line = new Line2D.Double(1065, 209, 1066, 209);
            g2.draw(line);
            colors.add(color);
            components.add(line);
            g2.scale(2, 2);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not entirely sure if it's is the issue here "GUI things" like repainting and so on should always be executed by the event thread, in your case

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.setLocation(x, y);
        this.repaint();
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but, where do I need to put this codes?

Comment: At the same location you want setLocation and repaint to be invoked - meaning in the same place where they are invoked right now.